# Reading the data from Pelops client and benchmark the read operation

Tags: java, cassandra, pelops

I am trying to read the data from `Cassandra database` using `Pelops client`. I am successfully able to do that.

Now I have started doing `benchmarking`, meaning how much time read takes from Cassandra database. So I have added my `benchmarking code` in below code.

Now I am not sure whether I have added my `benchmarking code` at correct place to measure the read latency of `Cassandra database` using `Pelops client` or not?

Below is my code-

```
public Map<String, String> getAttributes(final String rowKey, final Collection<String> attributeNames, final String columnFamily) {

    final Map<String, String> attributes = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        final SlicePredicate myPredicate = Selector.newColumnsPredicate(attributeNames.toArray(new String[attributeNames.size()]));

        final Selector selector = Pelops.createSelector(CassandraPelopsConnection.getInstance().getPoolName());

        // this is the right place to start the timer?
        CassandraTimer timer = CassandraTimer.getInstance();

        final List<Column> columnList = selector.getColumnsFromRow(columnFamily, rowKey, myPredicate, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

       // And this is the right place to end the timer incase of Pelops client?
        timer.getDuration();

        for (Column column : columnList) {
            attributes.put(new String(column.getName()), new String(column.getValue()));
        }       
    }  catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether I am doing right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct, you want the timer to start exactly before the query, and stop immediately after your query.

As a side note, you're not doing anything with the timer, assign it to a variable so you can use it later.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am assuming by this line only `selector.getColumnsFromRow(columnFamily, rowKey, myPredicate, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);` It will go and fetch the data from Cassandra database. So if my assumpotions is right, I have put the timer at right place. Yeah regarding the timer, I am already having a static map in that get duration method which I am using later on.